# Two different prices for the one product on the checkout page (bug)

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

The correct price for the product is €38 and VAT is included to the price @23%

In the products page the price 30.89 plus 23% = 30.894*1.23 = 37.99962

But when I add a product and go tho the cart, the total price and the cart prices are out by a cent

[image: picture ot cart]

the cart is €38 but the check out is €38.01

I tried every combination possible to get both prices correct and I can get €37.99 and €40.01 but I can't get €40 in both carts.

I'm not sure how they could be different I thought they would be going by the same calculation but obviously not.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [rounding issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/14458). Try increasing the number of decimals in WooCommerce > Settings > General

[image: WooCommerce Settings]

Comment: Thanks, that helps with this product not too sure how it will effect other products.